# TypeError: _ is not a function while writing jest unit test case in react

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, testing, jestjs

I have a function as shown below

```
export const getTopL1L2Errors = (data) => {
    const dataByPriority = [];
    data.forEach((record, counter) => {
        if (record['New Lv1-Lv2'] !== '#N/A') {
            dataByPriority.push(record);
        }
    });
    const result = _(dataByPriority)
        .countBy('New Lv1-Lv2')
        .map((count, l2CaseName) => ({ l2CaseName, count }))
        .value();
    const sortedL2List = _.orderBy(result, ['count'], ['desc']);
    const top10List = sortedL2List.slice(0, 10);
    return top10List ;
};
```

where i am using loadash for countBy,orderBy thelogic works good but when i run the test case in jest

```
TypeError: _ is not a function

  62 |         }
  63 |     });
> 64 |     const result = _(dataByPriority)
     |                    ^
  65 |         .countBy('New Lv1-Lv2')
  66 |         .map((count, l2CaseName) => ({ l2CaseName, count }))
  67 |         .value();
```

Even though i have imported the loadash in the file
import * as _ from 'lodash';

New in writing test case not sure what is work please help me to fix this

Comment: I had the same issue with lodash.find.  
I changed from `import * as _find from 'lodash.find'` to `import _find from 'lodash.find'`.  Maybe try `import _ from 'lodash'` and see if it works for you.  

Also this only seemed to be a problem in the Jest test as well.

Comment: When I look into this more, its seems to be Node and Jest and handling of these types of imports.  There could be a babel solution.  Sorry I don't have an answer just a possible import workaround.